# Django Rest Framework - Customize LimitOffsetPagination

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pagination

I tried to include Pagination in my Django Rest Framework to limit the number of outputs the query provides. For that I used `LimitOffsetPagination`.
Here is my output:

```
{
    "count": 59,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/getContacts/?limit=3&offset=3",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "contactName": "Mr.Important"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "contactName": "Mrs.VeryImportant"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "contactName": "Mr.NotSoImportant"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to customize the output so that the `next` & `previous` links appear within the `results` JSON object?
What I want is something like :

```
{
    "count": 59,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/getContacts/?limit=3&offset=3",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "contactName": "Mr.Important",
            "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/getContacts/?limit=3&offset=3",
            "previous": null,
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "contactName": "Mrs.VeryImportant"
            "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/getContacts/?limit=3&offset=3",
            "previous": null,
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "contactName": "Mr.NotSoImportant",
            "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/getContacts/?limit=3&offset=3",
            "previous": null,
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You just want to repeat the `next` and `previous` links within each result, despite it being WET? I've never done that, but here's an example that might help get you started: https://github.com/wharton/automagic-rest/blob/master/automagic_rest/pagination.py#L40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination classes are helpless here because they are meant to take ***N-number of items*** and returning a few items by ***slicing the inputs***.
Here, the requirement is a kind of ***response alteration***, so we override the [**`dispatch()`**--DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#dispatch-methods) method of the view class.

```
class MyView(...):
    def alter_response_data(self, _json_response):
        json_response = _json_response.copy()
        results = []
        next_ = json_response['next']
        previous_ = json_response['previous']

        for item in json_response['results']:
            item.update({'next': next_, 'previous': previous_})
            results.append(item)
        json_response['results'] = results
        return json_response

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        http_response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        json_response = http_response.data

        if 'next' in json_response and 'previous' in json_response:
            http_response.data = self.alter_response_data(json_response)

        return http_response
```